# $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent metrics on a set $X$ if and only if there exists a metric space $(Y,\rho)$ and a homeomorphism $h:X\rightarrow Y$

Tags: metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Prove that two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ on a set $X$ are equivalent if and only if there exists a metric space $(Y,\rho)$ and a homeomorphism $h:X\rightarrow Y$ from $X$ onto $Y$ such that $d_2(x,y)= \rho (h(x),h(y))$ for $x,y \in X$.

I know the basic definitions and properties of homeomorphism and equivalent metrics, but I am blank on this. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: There is something wrong with this question. The RHS of the equivalence does not mention $d_1$ and is always true. (Take $Y=X$, $\rho=d_2$.) The LHS is obviously not always true.

Comment: @user8734617 Thanks for the hint. But, why is the LHS not always true? Do you mean that LHS and RHS are not equivalent? I came across this exercise in a text.

Comment: Because not every two metrics are equivalent. (Take for example ordinary metric on $\mathbb R^n$ and discrete metric on the same set.)

Comment: @user8734617 Of course. We have to assume that they are equivalent in order to show RHS is true.

Comment: RHS is always true, no matter what $d_1$ is, as $d_1$ is not even mentioned in the RHS. LHS is not true if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are not equivalent. $RHS$ will be true in that case as you will take $Y=X, \rho=d_2, h=id_X$.

Comment: @user8734617 Now I get your point. Thank you so much for explaining!

Comment: I wonder how this exercise got to be set up so wrong... Is the text in English? (Is it maybe badly translated?) Could there be a simple typo that explains it? If the text is written by someone you have access to, by any means please ask them what they meant.

Comment: @user8734617 I found this exercise in a collection of study notes provided by our professor. I did not think there would be some typo. Maybe he could provide some clarification.

Comment: Indeed, and you can also point him to this question on Math.SE and this conversation thread, he will be able to tell where the mistake is.